# Trigger custom event without eventEmitter in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component with an event on it like this:

```
<menu-elem (onClick)="reallyCoolEvent($event)"></custom-component>
```

Right now, i can trigger my `reallyCoolEvent` with an EventEmitter from my `custom-component`.

```
@Output() onClick= new EventEmitter();
this.onClick.emit(stuff);
```

Like this, in my other component the function `reallyCoolEvent` will be called and the `stuff` will be passed to that function. That works really well!

Now, lets say, I want to copy that component for whatever reason and I want to trigger the same event from the original. Right now, I'm going through my list of `onClick` and if they macth my criteria I store them in a list that I show somewhere else on the page. When I trigger the `onClick` from there the event is never triggered.

```
<menu>
  <menu-elem label="Action 1" (onClick)="superCoolEvent($event)"></menu-elem>
  <menu-elem label="Action 2" (onClick)="superCoolEvent2($event)"></menu-elem>
  <menu-elem label="Action 3" (onClick)="superCoolEvent3($event)"></menu-elem>
</menu>
```

In `menu`:

template:

```
<div>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<sub-menu *ngFor="let subMenu of subMenus" [style.top]="subMenu.top" [style.left]="subMenu.left" [items]="subMenu.items"></sub-menu>
```

In `sub-menu`:

template:

```
<menu-elem *ngFor="let item of items" [label]="item.label"></menu-elem>
```

By doing that, I would like to be able to trigger the `onClick` within the `<div class="here">` and still trigger the event from the original template : `reallyCoolEvent($event)`. I don't know if I can do that or not. Of course the `onClick` is not set because I don't have the data anymore from the template. Or at least, I don't know how to get the data.

The only solution that I have so far, is to duplicate my entries like this:

```
<menu>
  <menu-elem label="1" (onClick)="superCoolEvent($event)"></menu-elem>
  <menu-elem label="2" (onClick)="superCoolEvent2($event)"></menu-elem>
  <menu-elem label="3" (onClick)="superCoolEvent3($event)"></menu-elem>
  <div class="test">
    <menu-elem label="1" (onClick)="superCoolEvent($event)"></menu-elem>
    <menu-elem label="2" (onClick)="superCoolEvent2($event)"></menu-elem>
    <menu-elem label="3" (onClick)="superCoolEvent3($event)"></menu-elem>
  </div>
</menu>
```

And depending of my criteria I can show them or not, but I don't like that way since the template gets too big for nothing.

Comment: Could you provide a less abstract example that illustrates the actual problem?

Comment: Why don't you create an extendable component which can allow you to define the count of replication and an array list of functions to bind?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that custom events don't bubble in Angular.

Since your `menu` looks like this:

```
<div>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<sub-menu *ngFor="let subMenu of subMenus" [items]="subMenu.items"></sub-menu>
```

Any event triggered within `sub-menu` in the template above won't automatically be available outside outside of `sub-menu`.

So, if you want the `customEvent` from within your `sub-menu` template to be available outside of `sub-menu`, you have to manually propagate the event through. Something like:

```
<div>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="here">
  <sub-menu *ngFor="let item of items" label="item.label" (submenuCustomEvent)="menuCustomEvent.emit($event)"></sub-menu>
</div>
```

where `submenuCustomEvent` is an `EventEmitter` property of `sub-menu` and `menuCustomEvent` is an `EventEmitter` property of `menu`.

**EDIT:**

That means that your `sub-menu` has to look something like:

```
@Component({
  .....
  template: `   
    <menu-elem *ngFor="let item of items" 
         [label]="item.label"
         (customEvent)="submenuCustomEvent.emit($event)
    >
    </menu-elem>
   `
})
export class Submenu {
    .....
   @Output()
   submenuCustomEvent = new EventEmitter();
    ....
}
```

and your `menu` becomes:

```
@Component({
  .....
  template: `   
    <div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <sub-menu *ngFor="let subMenu of subMenus" 
       [items]="subMenu.items"
       (submenuCustomEvent)="menuCustomEvent.emit($event)"
    >
    </sub-menu>
   `
})
export class Menu {
    .....
   @Output()
   menuCustomEvent = new EventEmitter();
    ....
}
```

So, the template that you're using your `menu` now looks like:

```
<menu (menuCustomEvent)="superCoolEvent($event)">
  <menu-elem label="Action 1" (customEvent)="superCoolEvent($event)"></menu-elem>
  <menu-elem label="Action 2" (customEvent)="superCoolEvent2($event)"></menu-elem>
  <menu-elem label="Action 3" (customEvent)="superCoolEvent3($event)"></menu-elem>
</menu>
```

**Points to note:**

- If you need to distinguish which `menu-elem` nested within `sub-menu` emitted the event, you might have to add some additional information to the event emitted by `submenuCustomEvent`.
- I named the event emitters for `menu` and `sub-menu` differently in my example to highlight the difference, but you can use the same event emitter name in your code (i.e. call all the nested event emitters `onClick`)
- A service might help in this scenario to avoid the manual wiring up of event emitters through the component hierarchy. Using a service, your top level component that's using `menu` can be directly notified if a `menu-elem` within `sub-menu` is clicked, without having the intermediate event propagation
- Finally, you are using a custom `onClick` event. But if you use the browser `click` event directly, you could avoid the manual propagation since browser `click` events DO propagate. However, you don't have control over the shape of the emitted event, so there is that limitation.

Comment: Just like wrote to Aravindin his answer. I did what you've sugested too and  it didn't worked either. 

As far as I know for the `componentXCustomEvent` to trigger anything, that event must me on an element in the template. And since it never appears in the template, it's never fired. The only event in the templatem in my code and in your answer id `customEvent`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're trying to do, but unfortunately, it wont work since what you put in the `menuCustomEvent` on the `menu` element is static. I don't want it to be only one thing, I want it to be any of the `menu-elem`' s `customEvent`. If you take a look a each `menu-elem` they each have a different function to be called when `customEvent` is triggered.

Comment: Well, that was my point about if you need to distinguish which `menu-elem` got clicked within your `sub-menu`, then you need to add some additional information to your `sub-menu` `$event`. This info will then be passed through your `menuCustomEvent.emit`, and the top level component can have a single event handler that switches on that data and calls the different `superCoolEvent1, 2 or 3` event handlers.

Comment: Ok but if I want it to be all in the template, do you know if it's possible?

Comment: well, if i'm understanding you properly, then if you want your sub-menu to surface different events depending on what internal menu elem is clicked, you can create separate output event emitters for each menu elem in your sub menu, and then separate output event emitters for your menu. That way, you can bind your different event handlers in your top-level component to different events on your menu. That's one approach that you can take, if you want everything visible in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is as below

```
  <custom-component *ngFor="let item of items" label="item.label" (customEvent)="eventHandler($event)"></custom-component>
```

The corresponding code should be in component-x ts file

```
eventHandler(event){
   this.customEvent.emit(..)
}
```

This will trigger the customEvent() in your custom-component as in this line

```
<custom-component (customEvent)="reallyCoolEvent($event)"></custom-component>
```

So this method

```
reallyCoolEvent(event){
   ///here is your emitted object from component-x
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `reallyCoolEvent($event)` will be called, but still I've tried what you suggested and it didn't worked. Can you give me a little more details please.

Comment: Sure. Can you create a plunker

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you fully. However, you can inject a reference of Parent component to child and use parent's eventemiiter.

```
 constructor(private myParent: Parent) {}

 go() {
    this.myParent.custometEvent.emit(data);
 }
```